# Remove week number column in 'dojox.Calendar'

Tags: javascript, css, dojo, dojox.calendar

I've got a `dojox/calendar/Calendar` with `dateInterval: 'month'`, and I would like to remove the week number column that appears. Is there a way to do this in calendar object creation through any property ?

Comment: You want week to desepear and let the year visible ? or only weeks number at the right side ?

Comment: Hi bRIMOs,
I want to remove both; week number column and year. In my cases them appears at left side. Want to remove both, to display calendar view starting with column 'Monday', not the week number/year.
Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two ways to do this .

1. **The difficult way** : is to extend the `dojox/calendar/Calendar` and make your change ( require reading all the source code to apply change ).
2. **Easiest way**  : is to apply change on generated and set some new styles 
   you need both `dojo/dom-construct` and `dojo/dom-style` to have requested rendering.

Here you find second way demonstration : 
not that I've still place the year at the top right of the toolbar to know in which year currently you are . 
[image]

You can see demo in this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bRIMOs/c8kxftj4/) or see above snippet :

```js
require(["dojo/ready", "dojo/_base/declare", "dojox/calendar/Calendar", "dojo/dom-construct","dojo/dom-style","dojo/domReady!"],
function (ready, declare, Calendar,domConstruct,domStyle) {

 calendar = new Calendar({
    date: new Date(),
    dateInterval: "month",
    style: "position:relative;width:90%;height:90%",
  }, "calendar");
        
  domStyle.set(calendar.matrixView.columnHeader,'left','0px');
  domStyle.set(calendar.matrixView.columnHeader,'border-left','1px solid #B5BCC7');
  domStyle.set(calendar.matrixView.grid,'left','0px');
  domStyle.set(calendar.matrixView.grid,'border-left','1px solid #B5BCC7');
  domStyle.set(calendar.matrixView.itemContainer,'left','0px');
  domConstruct.destroy(calendar.matrixView.rowHeader);
domConstruct.place(calendar.matrixView.yearColumnHeader,calendar.matrixView.buttonContainer,"last");   
  domStyle.set(calendar.matrixView.yearColumnHeader,'margin-right','10px');
  domStyle.set(calendar.matrixView.yearColumnHeader,'margin-top','-23px');
  domStyle.set(calendar.matrixView.yearColumnHeader,'float','right');
  
});
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0; 
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Lucida Sans,Lucida Grande,Arial !important;
    font-size: 13px !important;
    background: white;
    color: #333;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dojox/calendar/themes/claro/Calendar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<body class="claro">
  <div id="calendar"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: @Ote does this solve your issue ? if so , please up and mark the answer as resolved ( like in this image => [image resolve post](http://i.stack.imgur.com/T8umg.png) ) thnks .

Comment: Thank you! This is simply perfect! I was able to remove colums but there was always some margins/blank space and added events were misaligned. Thank you!